# Node POST requests based on external events

Tags: python, node.js, api, post, raspberry-pi

I have a door sensor attached to a Raspberry Pi and the goal is for a Node script to make a POST request to my external API server anytime the door is opened and another POST request after the door closes.

The logic is to have the below python script, running on my Pi, regularly check if the door is opened or closed. My python script is running successfully, checking if the door is opened or closed; however, it only checks the status 1 time.

The below Node script is also working properly, which makes a POST request with the output of the python script.

**Ask:** How can the below scripts be modified to send a POST request to my server once the door is opened and another once the door is closed.

My first thought was to use Node Events & EventEmitter capabilities but I'm unsure on the implementation of this. Also, I'm under the assumption that the python script would have to constantly be polling the the door; so here, a while loop could be used?

**door.py**

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as io
io.setmode(io.BCM)

door_pin = 23

io.setup(door_pin, io.IN, pull_up_down=io.PUD_UP)

if io.input(door_pin):
    print("Door Opened")
else:
    print("Door Closed")
```

**door.js**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var rest = require('restler');

// String that will be sent to the command line, generating the door status
var doorCommand = "sudo python door.py"

exec(doorCommand, function cb(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null){
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }

    var doorStatus = stdout; // stdout shows if the door is opened or closed

    // Creates the door status POST request to the Rails server
    rest.post('http://192.168.6.109:3000/door/save', {
        data: {
          door: doorStatus
        }
    }).on('complete', function(data, response){
        console.log('door status code: ' + response.statusCode);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. I would suggest using a Node.js module such as [pi-gpio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pi-gpio) to read the GPIO ports directly instead of invoking a Python script. You would then use a [setInterval](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) call in Node.js to repeatedly check the door status and invoke your POST if the status changed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I've scrapped the Python script and since re-written everything with pi-gpio. Definitely feels much less hacky!

Comment: Also, would it make more sense to utilize the Node events module?

Comment: It all depends. If you are going to consume this info in multiple places in your code, events module makes sense. Otherwise, I'd just keep it simple.